# Calculation of weekly volumes with bottlenecks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently working on a model in Excel to determine what weekly volumes we get through the production line per week.
The challenge is that I have bottlenecks for selected processes.
I basically just want to enter a value X in a cell, which then distributes this value to the next weeks based on this maximum limit (bottleneck):

[image]

I would like to know how many weeks I need to produce 425 peaces with a max output of 50 per week.

How would you build the function to get this result?

Comment: `weeks = input / maxOutput`

Comment: `=MIN(50,$B$1-SUM($B$3:B3))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in comments above.

[image]

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B4`

```
=MIN(50,$B$1-SUM($B$3:B3))
```

---

And Fill Down!